# How to create a Json object from the Schema definitions of swagger

Tags: json, object, yaml, swagger, openapi

I am failing to to remove the outer array from the json request body that I want swagger to generate from the schema definitions.

I want to generate this object:

```
{
    "name": 
    { 
        "value": "test04" 

    },
    "mail": { 
        "value": "test04@gmail.com" 
    }
}
```

But swagger is giving me this:

```
[
  {
    "name": {
      "value": "string"
    },
    "mail": {
      "value": "string"
    }
  }
]
```

This is my definition section:

```
definitions:
  user:
    type: "object"
    properties:
       name: 
        type: object
        properties: 
          value: 
            type: string
       mail: 
        type: object
        properties: 
          value: 
            type: string
```

May you kindly assist. I am new to swagger. I am using version 2.0

Comment: Your schema definition is correct. Most likely there's an extra `type: array` somewhere in the parameter / request body / response definition. Can you post the complete YAML of the problematic operation?

Comment: you were right, thank you for your help. If you post this as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `User` schema is correct, so this means there's an extra `type: array` somewhere in the parameter, request body, or response where this schema is used.